# I have to split a string with '&' separated values without the use of a function or stored proc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I have a column `Variables`  in the table `Functions`, that contains a string of values separated by the `&` character that shows the inputs each student inserted into a function.

How would I go about splitting that string without the use of a function or stored procedure and the find the most commonly used variables? (I was thinking the latter part could be easily solved with a `COUNT(*)` and appropriate `GROUP BY`.)

Example of data:

```
StudentID     FunctionName    Variables

1             Example1        Var1=10&Var2=xy&Sign=True&Role=False
```

Comment: And may i ask if why you don't want to use functions ? because those built functions by SQL will resolve your issue.

Comment: Never store data as & separated data (or comma separated or whatever), it will only cause you lots of trouble. One value per row is the SQL way!

Comment: If it was up to me then of course i would not save data in that format however this is the data I was given to work with and the server we are working on has some permissions issues which does not allow for the creation of stored procs or functions. :( Thats my major issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning**

You may need first to sanitize input because XML is used.

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374984)**

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(StudentID INT, FunctionName NVARCHAR(100),  
Variables NVARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO #tab
VALUES (1,'Example1', 'Var1=10&Var2=xy&Sign=True&Role=False');


SELECT StudentId, FunctionName,
    Variable = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
FROM 
( 
  SELECT StudentId, FunctionName,
         x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(Variables, '&', '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
  FROM #tab
) AS a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i);
```

You can wrap splitted data with subquery/CTE and do any aggregations as you want.

**EDIT:**

**[LiveDemo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374997)**

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT StudentId, FunctionName,
    Variable = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
FROM 
( 
  SELECT StudentId, FunctionName,
         x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(Variables, '&', '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
  FROM #tab
) AS a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
)
SELECT 
  StudentId, FunctionName,
   Variable      = SUBSTRING(Variable, 1, CHARINDEX('=', Variable)-1)
  ,VariableValue = SUBSTRING(Variable, CHARINDEX('=', Variable)+1, LEN(Variable)-CHARINDEX('=', Variable)+1) 
FROM cte;
```

Result:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╦══════════╦═══════════════╗
║ StudentId ║ FunctionName ║ Variable ║ VariableValue ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╣
║         1 ║ Example1     ║ Var1     ║ 10            ║
║         1 ║ Example1     ║ Var2     ║ xy            ║
║         1 ║ Example1     ║ Sign     ║ True          ║
║         1 ║ Example1     ║ Role     ║ False         ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╩══════════╩═══════════════╝
```

**EDIT:**

Suppose your data contains `<` character. You need to change it to`&lt;`
[Other EntityReferences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd892769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
SELECT StudentId, FunctionName,
     [Variables] = REPLACE(REPLACE(Variables, '&', 'separator'), '<', '&lt;')
FROM #tab
```

**[LiveDemoWithDataSanitizing](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375064)**

Comment: Thank you so much Lad2025 , this should work for myself as it works here, however I forgot to state that my variables columm is of ntext data type so thats causing me some trouble at them moment.  Tried to use the following but didnt work.
`+ REPLACE(CAST(Variables as CHAR(8000)), '&', '</i><i>') `

Comment: @AC007 `CAST(Variables AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` and move on ;)

Comment: @AC007 By the way URL string variables has max size around  **2000** so I don't see point of `NTEXT` datatype

Comment: I think some of the values go way beyond the 2000 char mark. Btw just for future reference for anyone check this question out, now the error message is : XML parsing: line 1, character 430, illegal qualified name character. 
I thought this might have something to do with & being a special XML character so i switched it to `&amp;` and now i get a : 
XML parsing: line 1, character 49, semicolon expected error message. Argh! This is so frustrating :) But thanks for all the help dude, i ll figure something out with this lil error

Comment: This is a great solution for data that is in VALID XML , however apparently mine isnt as it contains certain ILLEGAL XML characters. Ugh back to the drawing board, I appreciate all the help though :)

Comment: is there anyway of checking if the XML output would be valid  and if it isnt can you then turn it into NULL so as to avoid the query from not running ?

Comment: @AC007 Please provide example in which XML fails and I will try to help you to sanitize it. You just need to do some replacing, that's all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92137/discussion-between-ac007-and-lad2025).